# IE not allowing scrolling when html set to 100%

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In ie when I try to make my background extend the length of the page using 100% on the body and html tag heights it removes the ability to scroll. Is there any way I can do both? I am testing this in ie8 but I am not sure if the problem exists elsewhere. If a link is needed to the page please request it and I can post it.  My background is a css gradient that fills the page on all browsers no matter the content height. In ie however the content height determines the height of the background. I looked this up and this can be fixed by

```
 html, body {height:100%;}//this results in a loss in the ability to scroll on pages with lengthy content but does produce a background that fills the page with short content.
```

or

```
html, body {min-height:100%}//this results in a background that falls short of the full page when short content is present
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your html tag.

Comment: actually I just realized, this produced 2 scroll bars on the right, one is dulled out the other usable and I need to put the overflow on the body, so i believe I have a scroll bar for html and for the body

Comment: so i fixed this by adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to the body tag and `overflow-y: hidden;` to the html tag